# "aggregate" on a string field in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a resultset from Backup logs (files) that contains details about every backup client.
Lets say each line contains columns:

```
ClientName    BackupObject   Status
----------------------------------- 
winsrv1       c:             Completed
winsrv1       d:/data/       Completed/Errors
winsrv1       d:/logs/       Completed
linux1        /data/         Aborted
etc.......................
```

Possible Status values are:

- Completed
- Errors
- Aborted
- Warrnings
- Completed/Errors
- Completed/Warnings
- some other.

I would like to group this resultset by ClientName and have Status that is calculated in such way that it shows most severe (strongest?) error from details row.

Only idea so far is to:

1. create lookup table for mapping StatusID to Status
2. create derived integer column "StatusID" and convert statuses for each line (Completed=1, Completed/Warnings=2, Aborted=4, etc.)
3. aggregate with MAX(StatusID) function , and group by ClientName
4. do Lookup transformation to add Status back to the grouped Resultset

While in theory this should work I feel it is not very elegant solution, not in the spirit of SSIS.
I am new to SSIS so I apologise if I asked obvious thing. I am still learning how SSIS works under the hood.

Comment: How do you decide what status is severe?

Comment: actually now that I implemented the idea above I realized that I can't categorize them by severity.
But enough would be if I can group them in three groups: Success, Failed, Aborted

Comment: or maybe: Completed, Not completed, Aborted